# Can I have a Joomla! section on my site

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have built my website using HTML, CSS and JQuery. All pages are .php and everything works the way I want it to. My business is expanding now and I need to add a log in section for my clients where I can manage all of the work I produce (photography).

Because a custom CMS is out of my knowledge of web design I have decided to learn / use Joomla! My question is will I be able to keep my existing website and have a section that is Joomla!? So the main site remains untouched but when a client goes to the login page that page and the CMS area are joomla!

I am on an Apache server and am basically not sure if I can have just part of my site Joomla! Or does it have to be 100% Joomla!?

If I cannot have just part of my the site built in Joomla! Then there is no point in me learning it. I will have to outsource the design of the CMS. Just don't want to waste my time learning Joomla for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla will happily coexist with your existing website but will likely need to be installed into a folder to avoid same file name conflicts (e.g. index.php).

Comment: Right, never thought of that. Good point. Thank you for your help. That is all I wanted to know, I will mark this as answered and go ahead and learn Joomla.